# How do I find the most common combinations of items on a grouped dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([{"order_id": 1234, "product": "milk"},
              {"order_id": 1234, "product": "butter"},
             {"order_id": 4321, "product": "bread"}, 
             {"order_id": 4321, "product": "milk"},
             {"order_id": 4321, "product": "butter"},
             {"order_id": 1111, "product": "corn"},
             {"order_id": 1111, "product": "cereal"},
             {"order_id": 8888, "product": "milk"}])

    order_id    product
0   1234    milk
1   1234    butter
2   4321    bread
3   4321    milk
4   4321    butter
5   1111    corn
6   1111    cereal
7   8888    milk
```

I need to find the most common combination of products, without having to infer how many products to put in these combinations.

This example shoud return milk and butter as the two most bought together itens.

I have tried grouping them by the order_id but could not find a solution to get the combinations inside the groups.

Comment: use `groupby`. it will give you the distinct list.

Comment: yes, groupby gives me the list, but I need to pick the combination that's the most common, the `groupby(['order_id', 'product']).size()` will give me only the orders grouped. I need the combination of products inside the orders

Comment: it is really not clear. can you say what you expect from that you sample list. I mean what is the combination you expect from yours.

Comment: If the problem asks for *all* combinations, it might be too hard/board. We can manage to do pairs though.

Comment: @MEdwin In the sample I have two different order_id with milk and butter and both contains both itens. I someone buys milk, it will probably buy butter as well, because most orders that contains milk, have butter with it.

Comment: @QuangHoang sounds like a starting point! We can do pairs first!

Comment: You might find useful this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28611/what-is-a-product-most-frequently-bought-together-with)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do find pairs of products by `merge` and `groupby.size`:

```
# merge on id to pair up the products
new_df = df.merge(df, on='order_id')

# first thing is to drop identical products
(new_df[new_df['product_x'].lt(new_df['product_y'])]
    .groupby(['order_id', 'product_x', 'product_y'])              # group
    .size()            # count (id, prod1, prod2)
    .sum(level=[1,2])  # sum over (prod1, prod2)
    .idxmax()          # get (prod1, prod2) with max count
)
```

gives you

```
('butter', 'milk')
```

Comment: That's it, Thanks! A little more complicated than I expected, but it works!

Comment: doesn't this returns pairs only?

Comment: @rpanai OP said in the comments that pairs would do for now.

Answer (score 1):

#### `itertools.combinations` and `pandas.Series.mode`

```
from itertools import combinations

pd.Series.mode([
    t for _, d in df.groupby('order_id').product
    for t in combinations(d, 2)
])

0    (milk, butter)
dtype: object
```

---

#### `collections.Counter`

Similar answer as above but using `Counter` instead of `pandas.Series.mode`

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

Counter([
    t for _, d in df.groupby('order_id').product
    for t in combinations(d, 2)
]).most_common(1)

[(('milk', 'butter'), 2)]
```

Comment: This looks so much better! With this approach, can we remove the hardcoded number of items in combination and use the algorithm to infer it for us?